# Repeat remove quotes from 48 fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, quotes

This script below works on a field by field basis, and removes the quotes at the beginning and the end of every entry, BUT if you have more than 3 or 4 columns, copying, pasting changing to every new column name takes a huge amount of time. Any idea how to have this perhaps loop through every column?

```
--Removing quotes back and front from fields where datetime_updated is not blank
UPDATE [Majestic].[dbo].hdiyouth_school_2
SET datetime_updated=left(right(cast(datetime_updated as nVarchar), 
    LEN(cast(datetime_updated as nVarchar))-1),
    LEN(cast(datetime_updated as nVarchar))-2)
WHERE datetime_updated IS NOT NULL AND datetime_updated LIKE '"%"'
```

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server Management Studio 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can auto-generate a query for each column, in a manner similar to this:

```
select 
'UPDATE [Majestic].[dbo].hdiyouth_school_2
SET ['+column_name+']=left(right(cast(datetime_updated as nVarchar), 
    LEN(cast(datetime_updated as nVarchar))-1),
    LEN(cast(datetime_updated as nVarchar))-2)
WHERE datetime_updated IS NOT NULL AND datetime_updated LIKE ''"%"'';'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Employee' and TABLE_SCHEMA='HumanResources'
```

Comment: Hi, how do I auto generate it? And where do I get details for the TABLE_SCHEMA?

Comment: Edit the TABLE_NAME and TABLE_SCHEMA to match the table you want to update, and run in SSMS against your database. Copy and paste the results to a new query tab.
The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views can be found in SSMS Object Explorer, under Views - System Views, in your DB tree.

Comment: Also please read https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx in case you extend this approach to more complicated scenarios. I stay away from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` because they're not complete and I'd rather code against the same set of metadata instead of try to memorize rules about what I can get from them and what I need to get elsewhere.